# Compare Mouse X,Y with Grid X,Y to find the closest grid position

Tags: javascript

**EDIT:
From two very good answers I have decided to use isometric projection instead of my silly grid of cordinates.**

I am doing a game entirely in canvas, and I find it quite troublesome right now.

I felt silly trying to post the grid. Here is the code with the grid on hastebin.com

[Hastebin Link](http://hastebin.com/gobacosoko.coffee)

Since I have all the grid cordinates, I am iterating the 2D array and turn each iteration into a vertex that I compare to the mouse vertex. 
My goal is to find the vertex closest to the mouse vertex.
Instead all I am returning right now is (17,0) every time, no matter where I click.  Do you have any idea why?

```
function mouse_click(ev) {
    var x = ev.clientX - c.offsetLeft;
    var y = ev.clientY - c.offsetTop;
    // Run click_grid
    alert(click_grid(x,y));



}

// Find the grid that is nearest the clicked cordinates.
function click_grid(xx,yy){
    var result = [];
    var result2 = [];
    var best = [0,0];
    var lastNode = [];
    var currentNode = 9000;
    for(var y = 0;y < 18; y++){
        for(var x = 0; x < 18; x++){
            // Distance = |P-E| = |(3,3)-(1,2)| = |(2,1)| = sqrt(2'2+1'2) = sqrt(5) = 2.23
            result = [grid.grid_x[y][x] - yy,grid.grid_y[y][x] - xx];
            result2 = [result[0] * result[0], result[1] * result[1]];
            currentNode = Math.sqrt(result2[0] + result2[1]);
            if(currentNode < lastNode){
                best = [y,x];
            }
            lastNode = currentNode;
        }
    }
    return([best]);
}
```

Comment: I think `currentNode` needs to start "OVER 9000!", it's currently equal to 9000. But seriously, I think this question is a bit too localized for the site. Since it's just a debugging issue with your code. You may want to ask a new question about what the best way to go about this might be, since your current method looks a little overkill.

Comment: I think you are right :)

Comment: I create a new, better question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your grid, this is a simple isometric projection. Typically, we use linear algebra to figure out the coordinates, rather than iterating over all the grid coordinates.

For example: we know, based on your data, that the transformation looks something like this.

```
map (0,0) <-> screen (340,0)
map (0,1) <-> screen (360,10)
map (1,0) <-> screen (320,10)
```

We can derive the formula:

```
mapcoordinates = [-x/40+y/20+8.5, x/40+y/20-8.5 ]
```

for example, if you try out this code, it should alert the same results (sans bounds checking) I flipped x and y because of the choice of coordinates labels is reversed, and I added 0.5 and then converted to integer (`>>0`) to handle rounding to the "nearest" coordinate:

```
function click_grid(x,y) { 
   return [-y/40+x/20+9>>0,y/40+x/20-8>>0];
}
```

Comment: Does this mean.. I could avoid a messy grid like the one I have on the link and replace it with a 2 coordinate grid and do that calculation to find the positions? That would currently remove two of my 3 arrays. Which would be nice.

Comment: yes, you don't need a grid of coordinates to search through. That's an extremely wrong way of doing isometric tiles.

Comment: Thank you! I was starting to think about using a Rectangle Polygon: 
http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b603/oliverschoening/hundevertex_zpsd4c6fa81.png

Comment: I do not fully grasp your example, I am going to to some google searches on  isometric tiles and grid coordinates algebra.  Does that sound like the correct thing to "google"?

Comment: Yes, sounds about right.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to move `lastNode = currentNode;` inside the `if` like:

```
        if(currentNode < lastNode){
            best = [y,x];
            lastNode = currentNode;
        }
```

Comment: No, then it would never loop through any nodes.

Comment: currentNode is the distance from the mouse to the currentNode right?  lastNode is the distance from the mouse to the previousNode in the list right?

Comment: If that's right, you want to initialize last node to something really large (9000), and move "lastNode = currentNode" inside the if statement.  Otherwise I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did that now, it did actually change something although I don't see why it should, it is the best[array] that gets returned, all this did was reduce the amount of times lastNode changes ?

Comment: "lastNode" should really be named "bestDistance" and "currentNode" is "currentDistance".  So you only want to update the "bestDistance" if your current distance is better than your previous best distance.